# how can I extract out this ruby code as a method that converts a hash to variables?

Tags: ruby, json, methods

I have the following code spread out across a bunch of methods:

`json_element` is passed as an argument to the method.
 issues:

- The values in the hash change, meaning one could have `key` but the next time could have `search`
- sometimes the value is `nil` so it blows up.
- The gem I used which creates it has those ['$'] for elements if there's a value, but it errors out if you do `json_element['COLLECTION']['$].nil?`

  ```
    json = json_element['JSON']['$'] unless json_element['JSON'].nil?


    predicate = json_element['PREDICATE']['$'] unless json_element['PREDICATE'].nil?
    key = json_element['KEY']['$'] unless json_element['KEY'].nil?
    options = json_element['OPTIONS']['$'] unless json_element['OPTIONS'].nil?
    cache_key = json_element['CACHE-KEY']['$'] unless json_element['CACHE-KEY'].nil?
  ```

**question: how can I extract this whole bit as a method which allows for flexible keys and doesn't error out when a value is nil**

Comment: are you trying to ask how can you override a method?

Comment: I want to extract this code as a method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand this right. If the values in the hash are `nil`, it shouldn't error out. The variables would just be assigned `nil`. `#nil?` also shouldn't error out.

Just refactoring your code into a method:

```
def process(json_element)
  return if json_element.nil?
  hash = {} # store the variables in a hash
  %w{json predicate key options cache-key}.each do |i|
    hash[i.upcase] = json_element[i.upcase]['$'] unless json_element[i.upcase].nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: It errors out because nil['$'] errors out. The $ element where the actual value is stored is why makes this more complicated that a regular hash.

Comment: This won't work because the values iterated over are not static: e f json predicate key etc are not always the same from call to call.

Comment: How about passing the values to be iterated over as an argument?

Comment: What do you mean?  The hash value if nil causes the [$] element to error since it looks like applying a method on nil

Comment: You said `json, predicate` etc are not same from call to call - those values can be passed as an argument to the function. I'm still not sure I understand your nil case. If `json_element` is nil, method will return. If `json_element[key]` is nil, the line is skipped.

Comment: It looks like predicate options key are hard coded. But those keys a different based on the elements. Is there a way to not hard code it?

Comment: Probably, but you'll need to post a specific example.